# Changing MTU on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, xbox360, mtu

have tried several times to change the mtu on my windows 8 hp laptop, have used the method shown here- 
http://www.richard-slater.co.uk/archives/2009/10/23/change-your-mtu-under-vista-windows-7-or-windows-8/
But in command prompt it says 'the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect'

My issue is connecting my xbox to a wireless and the only error message is shows is an MTU error.

Thanks all!

Comment: If your Xbox is showing an MTU error, then you will need to change the MTU on the Xbox. I don't know if that's possible. The last time I had a non-PC device fail with an MTU error, it was impossible to fix. Perhaps you will need to use ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's not "Wireless Network Connection" for the type of connection it may be "Wi-Fi". However the MTU will most likely reset after restarting your computer for unknown reasons.